# Validate a Form Submit before submitting and writing a result into a field, that will then be submitted - using Prevent default and Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

When I press the Form Submit button, I want to action some validation (via an Ajax call), and change a screen value, before the Form is actually submitted.

My issue is that when I try this, and I manually action the Submit button, the screen value is not actually updated until the Form has been submitted. Too late!

Is there any way around this issue?  I've tried to comment in the code exactly what I mean.

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
  // we prevent teh default action of the udpate button
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('In Jquery/JS.. button pressed / Prevented default');
  // variables for "self" so we can access the form
  // nativley using javascript and not jquery
  var self = this,
    root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
  // Now call Ajax, get results, and if good, manually call the
  // submit button.
  $.ajax({
    url: root + '/posts/1',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
      alert('in ajax success');
    }
  }).done(function (data) {
    alert('in ajax done - Title data = : ' + data.title);
    if (data.title !== "") {
      // We assign our Input Text field some data
      $('#textfield').val(data.title);
      // The on screen value actually hasn't updated :o(
      alert('about to self submit');
      // We go to submit... but our form isn't actually
      // updated with the Ajax text yet...
      // is that possible before we action the submit???
      self.submit();
    }
  }).fail(function () {
    alert('error');
  });
});
```

See JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dave_pace/890zmj1f/

Comment: use jquery validato plugin to validate your form before submit https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: thanks for the info - but I'm limited to what scripts i can call by a client.  I'll check it out though.

Answer (score 1):

It is not what you think. [JavaScript is single-threaded](http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/03/14/wrapping-your-head-around-async-programming/). Therefore, an `alert` statement is executed just after its previous statement. It doesn't wait for the previous statement to finish.

Adding to that, `alert` is quicker than setting the value in the textbox, and it actually blocks the thread until it is dismissed. That's why you cannot see the value set in the textbox, but can see the submit alert first.

Your fiddle is fine, and works as it should. If you want to test this, try to remove all the alert statements from your code, and try to submit your form to an actual URL, for example `https://www.google.com`.

Though submitting to Google will result in an error, you can actually see that the textbox is being populated before the submit happens.

Comment: Thank you - I've updated the Fiddle to show the form being submitted with the correct data being passed.